# Export/ Import alembic trouble / blender 2.9

Tags: fluid-simulation, alembic

I got some trouble with alembic export/import.
I tried to export and reimport a fluid simulation but when i do so the importet mesh is not animatet.
Further are all stages of the animation on top of each other.

I used the "flip fluid" addon for the simulation.
Any ideas of what im doing wrong ?

sorry for my bad english x)[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you are using an older version of the FLIP Fluids addon (Current version is v1.0.8a), and this could be the reason why the mesh is not exporting the animation at default settings. A workaround is to add a modifier to the simulation meshes so that Blender recognizes these as animated meshes. Here is a link to an older version of the documentation with more information: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Alembic-Export-Support/757c909c12d35393c45e9c1f688ab92eb7f3872d#how-to-export-to-an-alembic-abc-cache

Comment: Thanks alot =) seems like the issue was the old version of flip fluid.